# Adding Attribute Data Bindings to Dynamically Created Elements in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I have a form for submitting data in Polymer that ends up looking something like:

```html
<paper-input name="username" label="Username" on-blur="_onUsernameInput" required></paper-input>
<span class="invalid" hidden$="[[usernameValid]]">invalid</span>
```

The idea is that each input in the form has a validation function (e.g. "_onUsernameInput". The input is followed by the text "invalid" which is either hidden or not based on whether the validation function passes.

However, the fields I am creating in the form are dynamic:

```js
// add new form input
var toAdd = document.createElement("paper-input");
toAdd.label = args[i].name;
toAdd.id = args[i].id;
toAdd.addEventListener("blur", args[i].verificationMethod);
Polymer.dom(insertPoint).appendChild(toAdd);

// add new "invalid" text to show or hide on validation
var spanAdd = document.createElement("span");
var prop = args[i].id + "Valid";
Polymer.dom(spanAdd).setAttribute("hidden", "[[" + prop + "]]"); // ?!?!?!
Polymer.dom(insertPoint).appendChild(spanAdd);
```

The point where I get stuck is in the line denoted "?!?!?!" -- how do I dynamically add an attribute with a binding (in this case, the hidden attribute bound to a boolean that will determine whether or not the "invalid" text will be visible).

Comment: Are you using Polymer 1.0?  Are you trying to run the JavaScript shown in a custom Polymer element or using a Auto-binding template?  Can you include example HTML and `args` data?

Comment: @Adam Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557807/can-dynamically-created-local-light-dom-in-polymer-be-processed-to-ensure-correc