# Can dynamically created Local/Light DOM in Polymer be processed to ensure correct bindings?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to modify local/light `DOM` from JS within a custom element in a way that would process bindings for thus dynamically added elements as if they were specified in `template`?

Please consider the following snippet (a part of a custom element):

```
...
            attached: function () {
                var node = document.createElement('div');                        
                Polymer.dom(node).innerHTML = '[[_computedValue()]]';
                Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(node);
                Polymer.dom.flush();
            },

            _computedValue: function() {
                return "some value";
            },
...
```

What I would like to happen is for the added `div` to have its inner HTML equal to the value returned from method `_computedValue`. The value cannot be assigned at the time of `div` creation as in the real situation it would depend on the realtime context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that for now Polymer 1.0 does not support dynamic (imperative) bindings. [Here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1778) and [here](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1796) are the relevant discussions.

The information from the above links suggests a reliable, albeit limited, approach to creation of dynamic content with bindings by means of using `dom-bind` template elements. The limitation is due to bindings working strictly with locally defined methods and properties for the `dom-bind` instance being created.

Here is an example, where `domBind` is created imperatively with properties `tapCount`, `tapMessage` and method `_tapMe`. The latter is used as `on-tap` event handler for the added to the `domBind` element `div`.

```
attached: function () {
   var domBind = document.createElement('template', 'dom-bind');
   domBind.tapCount = 0;
   domBind.tapMessage = 'Tap me now!';
   domBind._tapMe = function(e) {
                this.tapCount = this.tapCount + 1;
                this.tapMessage = 'Tapped ' + this.tapCount + ' time(s).';
   };
   var div = domBind.content.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = '<b on-tap="_tapMe">[[tapMessage]]</b>';
   domBind.content.appendChild(div);
   Polymer.dom(this.$.container).appendChild(domBind);
   Polymer.dom.flush();
}
```

A similar to my question is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836412/polymer-1-0-injectboundhtml-alternative), which helped me to get a better appreciation for the scope of the problem (especially with the reference to Polymer 0.5 injectBoundHTML).

---

Of course, external methods and properties can still be accessed:

```
...
var self = this;
domBind.externalMethod = function() {
    return self._computeValue();
};
...
```

Then by binding locally defined `externalMethod` one can "bind" things from the "external" scope. In this case, `_computeValue` refers to a method defined on a custom element with imperative light DOM construction happening in its method `attached`.