# Polymer 1.0 dynamic template with dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, templates, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a scenario where I would like to create dynamic `template` elements that will be used with Polymer's `dom-repeat`.

My current prototype is the following ([JSbin demo](http://jsbin.com/hitotahoqe/edit?js,output)):

```
var domRepeat = document.createElement('template', 'dom-repeat');
domRepeat.items = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var div = domRepeat.content.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '[[item]]';
domRepeat.content.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(domRepeat);
Polymer.dom.flush();
```

*However*, this does not work as intended. The output is:

```
[[item]]
[[item]]
[[item]]
```

rather than:

```
a
b
c
```

Since the `[[item]]` is printed out 3 times, I guess the `dom-repeat` itself works, but the data binding does not.

**Plot twist**: but if I change the example from `dom-repeat` to `dom-bind`, then the data binding *does* work. Changed example, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31575728/4623467) ([JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/gejifokowo/1/edit?js,output)):

```
var domBind = document.createElement('template', 'dom-bind');
domBind.item = 'Hello World!';
var div = domBind.content.ownerDocument.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '[[item]]';
domBind.content.appendChild(div);
document.body.appendChild(domBind);
Polymer.dom.flush();
```

The output is `Hello World!`, as expected.

Any ideas on how to get the first example to work?

Answer (score 3):

Binding in dynamically created HTML isn't that easy currently. I think there are plans to support this better eventually.

In the meantime Templatizer should allow to implement such a scenario.
I haven't used it myself and haven't found code examples.
iron-list and dom-if, dom-bind, dom-repeat seem to make use of it which might work as template for custom implementations.

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/templatizer.html

This might help http://t-code.pl/blog/2015/08/polymer-templatizer/

Comment: I am aware of the Templatizer. I have even modified the stock `dom-repeat` component so that instead of `this.templatize(this)` it templatizes an on-the-fly created `template`. Long story short: it kind of works, but has problems when you use `dom-bind` to bind other variables (that are outside of the scope of the modified `dom-repeat`). Seems like you also need to link the outside scope to the new template. But I have no idea how.

Comment: I see. As mentioned I have no experience with this myself. This question seems similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557807/can-dynamically-created-local-light-dom-in-polymer-be-processed-to-ensure-correc mabe it contains some ideas you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have already seen that. The second example in my question is actually inspired from that answer. I have updated my question so that it has a reference to it.

Comment: I've been playing a bit with `iron-list` and found out that when you swap the template with an on-the-fly created one, the data binding starts working *only* for stamped variables (index, selected, tabIndex, and item). Looks like other variables are already evaluated when stamping occurs.